# Twig JS Inline template unable to parse

Tags: javascript, templates, youtube, youtube-api, twig

I'm new to Twig.js templating and having some trouble getting it to render some JSON correctly. I'm using jQuery to pull a JSON result from Youtube and passing it to an inline Twig template. Everything's working fine except within my template the actual text I need to extract from the JSON is under `item.title.$t` and the `$` seems to be throwing it off. I get the error `Unable to parse '$t' at template position0`.

My full function is as follows:

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=stack+overflow&max-results=5&&v=2&alt=json', function(data){
  var template = twig({
    id: 'videos',
    data: '{% for item in feed.entry %}<h1>{{ item.title.$t }}</h1>{% endfor %}'
  });
  var postsHTML = twig({ ref: "videos" }).render(data);
  // Display the rendered template
  document.getElementById("videos").innerHTML = postsHTML;
});
```

Is there a way to escape strange characters such as `$` within a template? I can't find reference to such an ability in the documentation. I know the data is getting read in correctly as I can render the `title` object, just not it's `$t` propoerty. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tweaking I tried accessing the property as an array again and it worked. See below:

```
'{% for item in feed.entry %}<article><header><h1>{{ item.title[\'$t\'] }}</h1></header></article>{% endfor %}'
```

Comment: `{{ item['title'] | escape }}` is safer

Comment: I don't think that would work since the data I want to retrieve is at `item['title']['$t']` so using that solution would just return an object and not the string itself.